# Structure function with async closure variable

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, closures

I'm trying to do sth maybe very odd but I'm stack with the following problem.

I have a struct with a closure property which I set async functions.

What I want is, to call this async function to get the return value.

I can solve this with a workaround solution, but I want to do it with the right way.

Any help is appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
struct Item {
  var myselector: (String -> Void)?
  func getMeThat(completion: String -> Void) {
    completion(myselector()) // error: cannot call value of non-function type String -> Void
  }
}

class API {
  class func requestThing(completion: String -> Void) {
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(2 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))), dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
      completion("Kenan")
    })
  }
}

class ViewController {
  func viewDidLoad() {
    var item = Item()
    item.myselector = { // error: cannot assign value of type () -> () to type String -> Void
      API.requestThing({ (str: String) in
        <#code#>
      })
    }
    item.getMeThat({ (rtn: String) in
      print(rtn)
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please edit the error messages directly into your question instead of a screenshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The major problem is the miss match you have with your signature due to a weird duplication.

You are setting a closure as a variable of the struct, but are also providing the completion to the function. Do one or the other.

```
struct Item {
    func getMeThat(completion: String -> Void) {
        API.requestThing(completion)
    }
}

class API {
    class func requestThing(completion: String -> Void) {
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(2 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))), dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            completion("Kenan")
        })
    }
}

class ViewController {
    func viewDidLoad() {
        let item = Item()
        item.getMeThat({ (rtn: String) in
            print(rtn)
        })
    }
}
```

---

If you just want to delay the execution of code this is how you do it

```
struct Item {
    var myselector: (Void -> Void)?
    func executeSelector() {
        guard let sel = myselector else {
            return
        }

        sel()
    }
}

class API {
    class func requestThing(completion: String -> Void) {
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(2 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))), dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            completion("Kenan")
        })
    }
}

class ViewController {
    func viewDidLoad() {
        var item = Item()
        item.myselector = {
            API.requestThing({ (str: String) in
                print(str)
            })
        }
        item.executeSelector()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You're right but I want to set the function as a variable and call it in somewhere else. It would work with this architecture if the functions were not have to be async.

Comment: I don't see how the async is problematic, you need to capture in the closure the item you need to still exist when the async call returns. The closure ends up being captured by the dispatch_after closure so it still exist at that moment with everything that it as itself captured.

Comment: Yess. Your second answer just fits what I want. Thank you so much for your effort.